# My login PHP code does nothing (undefined offset: 0)

Tags: php, html, authentication

im learning how to do a login in PHP, but my code doesn't seem to work! The error is: `Undefined offset: 0 (line 6)` Can you guys help me?

```
<?php


    include("config.php");
    session_start();

    if( $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"=="POST"] ) {


        $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
        $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

        $mypassword=mad5($pass);

        $sql ="SELECT username FROM contas WHERE username= '$myusername' and password= '$mypassword'";

        $result= mysqli_query($db, $sql);

        $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

        mysqli_free_result($result);

        if($count == 1) {

            $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;
            header("location: welcome.php");

        } else {

            $error="Nome de utilizador (username) ou palavra-passe(password) inválido.";

        }

    }
    mysqli_close($db);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `md5()`?? And not `mad5()` also don't use it. It's highly unsafe. Use password hash and password verify

Comment: Oh yes, i've just updated it... but it still doesn't work :/ And i'm using md5 just for now, i just want it to work, and then i'll upgrade it

Comment: This causes the 0 offset `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"=="POST"]`, because it compares the strings and then tries to access the array. It sould be `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]==["POST"]`.

Comment: @jh1711 almost, though add it as an answer.

Comment: @jh1711 the error is gone! Thanks! Such an obvious mistake. But when i click "Login" it still does nothing... not even the else error message appears... so weird :(

Comment: are you savind your user in the database with password in MD5 format? Maybe this can solve your problem. I think it is a good idea look the process that save the user in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<?php

require_once 'config.php';
session_start();

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST" && isset($_POST['username'],$_POST['password']) ) :

$user= null;
$username = $_POST['username'];
// i don't recommend using md5 you may wanna change it later 
$password = md5($_POST['password']);

$mysqli = new Mysqli('localhost','user','password','database');
$stmt   = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT `contas`.`username` FROM `contas` WHERE `contas`.`username`= ? AND `contas`.`password` = ? LIMIT 1');
$stmt->bind_param('ss',$username,$password);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($user);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();

if($user !== null) {
$_SESSION['login_user'] = $user;
header('location: welcome.php');
exit;
} else {

echo "Nome de utilizador (username) ou palavra-passe(password) inválido.";
exit;

}

else : 
// not post request ! 
endif;
```

Comment: Used prepared statements `+1`

Comment: you need to change your hashes, md5 is not safe. 
also use prepared statement all the time ! even when selecting data.

Comment: i recommend you follow this tutorial to make a simple user management system and try to add your touch to it : https://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL

Answer (score 2):

This Line:

```
 if( $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"=="POST"] ) {
```

change it to:

```
 if( $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST" ) {
```